# Use ocamlfind with ocaml interpreter, without compiling

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I have a file `main.ml` that uses some package that makes the command `ocaml main.ml` fail and report this error:

```
Error: Unbound module X
```

And the only solution I've found so far is to run:

```
ocamlbuild main.native -use-ocamlfind -package X
./main.native
```

But this compiles the file. Is there a way to just run the regular ocaml interpreter (`ocaml main.ml`) with some additional flags to make it find the package?

Answer (score 2):

You can put at the beginning of your file some top-level directives which find and load needed modules. For example, when I want to use `Core` library in my script I insert:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "core";;

open Core.Std
(* Code of my script *)
```

To use `topfind` package `ocamlfind` has to be installed (`opam install ocamlfind`)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use topfind and add `#require "core"` at the top of your file. If you want to avoid adding toplevel directives in your file, you can use `ocamlfind query -i-format -r` to compute the required include directories:

```
 ocaml $(ocamlfind query -i-format -r core) main.ml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also query the path of your package to ocamlfind :

```
ocamlfind query package_X
```

That will return the path of your package : `/path_to/packageX`

And then :

```
ocaml main.ml -I /path_to/packageX
```